# Find out difference and intersection in JavaScript array of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

Let me first explain the issue I am trying to solve.

I have an existing list of Tags(key-value pair), which will be loaded first when a UI dialog will open up.
Then user can add more tags, can remove tags or can edit the tags.
The API where I will pass the modified tag list, unfortunately, does not support edit. So edit means: delete the modified entry and add the new entry.

An example of the tags are:

```
const existingTags = [{
                    "key": "t1",
                    "value": "v1"
                }, {
                    "key": "t2",
                    "value": "v2"
                }
            ];
const modifiedTags = [{"key": "t1", "value": "v1"}, {"key": "t2", "value": "v2"}, {"key": "t3", "value": "v3"},];
```

The code I have tried out is this: (It somehow works, but not elegant). Looking for some element solution, if possible.

```
ï»¿<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Arrays</h1>
<h2>The concat() Method</h2>


<p id="demo">TagsToBeAdded</p>
<p id="demo1">TagsToBeRemoved</p>
<p id="demo2">FinalAddList</p>


<script>
const existingTags = [{
                    "key": "t1",
                    "value": "v1"
                }, {
                    "key": "t2",
                    "value": "v2"
                }
            ];
const modifiedTags = [{"key": "t1", "value": "v1"}, {"key": "t2", "value": "v2"}, {"key": "t3", "value": "v3"},];
const tagsToBeAdded = modifiedTags.filter(item1 => !existingTags.some(item2 => (item2.key === item1.key && item2.value === item1.value)));
let tagsToBeDeleted = existingTags.filter(item1 => modifiedTags.some(item2 => (item2.key === item1.key && item2.value !== item1.value)));
const tagsToBeRetained = existingTags.filter(item1 => !tagsToBeDeleted.some(item2 => (item2.key === item1.key && item2.value === item1.value)));
if (!tagsToBeAdded.length && !tagsToBeDeleted.length) {
                tagsToBeDeleted = existingTags.filter(item1 => !modifiedTags.some(item2 => (item2.key === item1.key)));
}

const finalTagsListToBeAdded= tagsToBeRetained.concat(tagsToBeAdded);

const children = JSON.stringify(tagsToBeAdded); 
const children1 = JSON.stringify(tagsToBeDeleted); 
const children2 = JSON.stringify(finalTagsListToBeAdded); 

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = children
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = children1
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = children2
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Some of the examples:

```
// Input
const existingTags = [{
                    "key": "t1",
                    "value": "v1"
                }, {
                    "key": "t2",
                    "value": "v2"
                }
            ];
const modifiedTags = [{"key": "t1", "value": "v1"}, {"key": "t2", "value": "v21"}, {"key": "t3", "value": "v3"}];

// Expected output:
tagsToBeAdded: [{"key":"t2","value":"v21"},{"key":"t3","value":"v3"}]
tagsToBeDeleted: [{"key":"t2","value":"v2"}]
finalTagsList: [{"key":"t1","value":"v1"},{"key":"t2","value":"v21"},{"key":"t3","value":"v3"}]
```

```
// Input:
const existingTags = [{
                    "key": "t1",
                    "value": "v1"
                }, {
                    "key": "t2",
                    "value": "v2"
                }
            ];
const modifiedTags = [{"key": "t1", "value": "v1"}, {"key": "t2", "value": "v2"}, {"key": "t3", "value": "v3"}];

// Expected output:
tagsToBeAdded: [{"key":"t3","value":"v3"}]
tagsToBeDeleted: []
finalTagsList: [{"key":"t1","value":"v1"},{"key":"t2","value":"v2"},{"key":"t3","value":"v3"}]
```

```
// Input:
const existingTags = [{
                    "key": "t1",
                    "value": "v1"
                }, {
                    "key": "t2",
                    "value": "v2"
                }
            ];
const modifiedTags = [{"key": "t1", "value": "v1"}];  // t2:v2 is removing

// Expected output:
tagsToBeAdded: []
tagsToBeDeleted: [{"key":"t2","value":"v2"}]
finalTagsList: [{"key":"t1","value":"v1"}]
```

```
// Input:
const existingTags = [{
                    "key": "t1",
                    "value": "v1"
                }, {
                    "key": "t2",
                    "value": "v2"
                }
            ];
const modifiedTags = [];  // all tags are dropped

// Expected output:
tagsToBeAdded: []
tagsToBeDeleted: [{"key":"t1","value":"v1"},{"key":"t2","value":"v2"}]
finalTagsList: []
```

Lodash is also ok.

Comment: Please give a complete example with input and expected output ...

Comment: Yes. Added now.

Comment: There is an npm package called `deep-diff` that does exactly what you need.  Check it out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-diff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create shallow copies of the original arrays. Search through the copied arrays for elements that are in both and move them to their own array.

This causes the copy of `existingTags` to be reduced to `tagsToBeDeleted`, the copy of `modifiedTags` to be reduced to `tagsToBeAdded`, and the moved duplicates end up in the unchanged tags.

The unchanged tag array is then concatenated with the `tagsToBeAdded` array to make `finalTagsList`.

Note that `modifiedTags` and `finalTagsList` are effectively the same thing. Because of this, the below could be optimized to just drop the duplicate elements from the array copies.

```js
const mangle = (existingTags, modifiedTags) => {
  const unchangedTags = [];
  existingTags = Array.from(existingTags);
  modifiedTags = Array.from(modifiedTags);
  for(let i = 0; i < existingTags.length; i++) {
    const a = existingTags[i];
    for(let j = 0; j < modifiedTags.length; j++) {
      const b = modifiedTags[j];
      if (a.key == b.key && a.value == b.value) {
        unchangedTags.push(a);
        existingTags.splice(i, 1);
        modifiedTags.splice(j, 1);
        i--;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    tagsToBeAdded: modifiedTags,
    tagsToBeDeleted: existingTags,
    finalTagsList: unchangedTags.concat(modifiedTags);
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A straight forward  (not necessarily the most efficient, but for a set of tags that's manually managable, I don't think it makes difference) approach would be the following. This assumes, that the `key` of a tag is unique and both, `key` and `value` are primitive types that can be compared with `===`. See the comments in code for explanation.

```js
const existingTags = [
  { "key": "t1", "value": "v1"}, 
  { "key": "t2", "value": "v2" },
  { "key": "t3", "value": "v3" }
 ];
  
const modifiedTags = [
  {"key": "t1", "value": "v1u"}, 
  {"key": "t3", "value": "v3"}, 
  {"key": "t4", "value": "v4"} 
 ];

//tags that exist in existingTags but not in modifiedTags have to be deleted, 
const delTags1 = existingTags.filter(x => 
  !modifiedTags.find(y => x.key === y.key));

//tags that exist in both but differ in value have to be deleted
const delTags2 = existingTags.filter(x =>
  !!modifiedTags.find(y => x.key === y.key && x.value !== y.value));

//tags that exist in modifiedTags but not in existingTags have to be added
const addTags1 = modifiedTags.filter(y => 
  !existingTags.find(x => x.key === y.key));

//tags that exist in both but have a different value have to be readded
const addTags2 = modifiedTags.filter(y => 
  existingTags.find(x => x.key === y.key && x.value !== y.value));

//tags that exist in both and have the same value have to be retained
const keepTags = existingTags.filter(x => 
  modifiedTags.find(y => x.key === y.key && x.value === y.value));


const finalDelete = [...delTags1, ...delTags2];
const finalAdd = [...addTags1, ...addTags2, ...keepTags];

console.log(JSON.stringify(finalDelete));
console.log(JSON.stringify(finalAdd));
```